# how to create an object from given class name in php?

Tags: php, class, static-methods

I have a variable $className which is name of declared class in php and I want

1. create an object of this class
2. lunch a static method of this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also the [Reflection API](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reflection). E.g.:

```
<?php
$rc = new ReflectionClass('A');
// question 1) create an instance of A
$someArgs = array(1,2,3);
$obj = $rc->newInstanceArgs($someArgs);

// question 2) invoke static method of class A
$rm = $rc->getMethod('foo');
if ( !$rm->isStatic() ) {
  echo 'not a static method';
}
else {
  $rm->invokeArgs(null, $someArgs);
}

class A {
  public function __construct($a, $b, $c) { echo "__construct($a,$b,$c)\n";}
  public static function foo($a, $b, $c) { echo "foo($a,$b,$c)\n";}
}
```

Comment: oh, I didn't expect this one to be accepted. Keep in mind that IMO there's nothing wrong with `new $className()` if it fits your needs. ReflectionClass lets you do more stuff but it also adds some complexity.

Answer (score 4):

```
$obj = new $className();

$var = $className::method();
```

Answer (score 3):

1:
    $obj = new $className

2:
    $className::someMethod($parameter)